HDR-10 file uploaded to YouTube keeps being changed to bt709?
Thanks to suggestions from a previous question, I was able to create my own "tone-mapper" in FCPX - add a color correction and set everything to zero, then add a Hue/Saturation and set the saturation to 0.8
See the attached screenshots, along with the original EXR which have nothing applied to them
https://youtu.be/M-tVtbg8-MM
Still trying to make YouTube recognize HDR-10 using mkvmerge on command line and according to MediaInfo this is an HDR-10 PQ file but YouTube keeps converting it to bt709.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. I have tried ffmpeg as well and MediaInfo keeps telling me that I have an HDR-10 file







Everything worked as expected. For some reason, there is a delay on the YT side and it could take from 24-48 hours for the HDR file to be present
Here is an example of waiting 24 hours for the HDR PQ file to display as an HDR:
First successful example
This is a playlist of the latest HDR PQ files
